# Photo slideshow in Google Sites that works without Flash?

Tags: google-plus, google-classic-sites, google-plus-photos, google-photos

Just inserted a Google+ photo album on a [web page](http://www.chaletlajoux.com/) built with Google Sites, then realized that it requires Flash! This means it doesn't display on my tablet, for example.

*Without requiring Flash, Is there a simple way to make a photo album available on Google Sites, and auto-play as a slideshow?*

Comment: "photos" is a meta tag that doesn't offer useful information and we're trying to retire it. Please see [Let's clean up some meta tags](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2696/354). The other tags seem to me to be tangential to your question. You need an expert on Google Sites. A Google+ expert isn't likely to be able to help.

Comment: @AlE. Well, this is all caused by a flaw in the official Google+ Photo Album gadget. If there is a workaround, then that'd be the easiest solution, and that's why I added the tags. The photos tag I'll remove.

Answer (score 3):

The Picasa Album embed is very old and not development is happening on the Picasa side anymore. Eventually Google Photos might roll out a album embed but they have announced no such plans.

In the meantime I would recommend looking at the community built [Picasa album web component](https://github.com/Scarygami/picasa-album/). You can see an [example of your album](https://jsfiddle.net/8krp0swj/) which you would obviously want to host the files on your own URL/site.

```
<script src="https://scarygami.github.io/picasa-album/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js" async defer></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://scarygami.github.io/picasa-album/components/picasa-album/picasa-album.html">
<picasa-album user="116506480591545018985" album="6195387128534811057" class="fit"></picasa-album>
```

Another option would be to use a [Google+ embedded post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/). [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/11x8kkqm/)

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/116506480591545018985/posts/eoAj7gtPjNB"></div>
```

Comment: Looks good. Now how do I utilize the Picasa album web component in *Google Sites?* From what I know, the HTML box cannot load external content.

Comment: You probably can't than. It looks like Sites has an embed Google+ post feature though so that option is still available.

Comment: It's almost certainly possible by including a custom gadget that utilizes the Picasa album web component. I remember writing a gadget in the past for including Flash content into Google Sites, but it's cumbersome, and I want to avoid it. In the end it may be simpler to write the entire page in HTML instead of using Sites.